# How to sort return result of Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch.

How should I modify the below code to make the return result descend sort by "lastpost" time?

Should I add "sort" below the "query" in the "body"

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/search')
def analyzer():
    bc = BertClient(ip='bertserving', output_fmt='list')
    client = Elasticsearch('elasticsearch:9200')

    query = request.args.get('q')
    query_vector = bc.encode([query])[0]

    script_query = {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['text_vector']) + 1.0",
                "params": {"query_vector": query_vector}
            }
        }
    }

    response = client.search(
        index=INDEX_NAME,
        body={
            "size": SEARCH_SIZE,
            "query": script_query,
            "_source": {"includes": ["title", "id","lastpost"]}
        }
    )
    print(query)
    pprint(response)
    return jsonify(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: yep, that is where I would put it.
```"sort" : {
    "lastpost": "desc"
}```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I edited the code as:

```
body={
        "size": SEARCH_SIZE,
        "sort": [{"lastpost": {"order": "desc"}}],
        "query": script_query,
        "_source": {"includes": ["title", "id","lastpost"]}
    }
```

but there still errors. And then I found that is because when I create index, the format are not matched, I didn't involved the "lastpost". So I edited my index.json:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "_source": {
      "enabled": "true"
    },
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lastpost": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "text_vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 768
      }
    }
  }
```

And now everything's good!

Answer (score 0):

Add sort in Body json like below:

```
body={
        "size": SEARCH_SIZE,
        "sort": {"lastpost": {"order": "desc"}},
        "query": script_query,
        "_source": {"includes": ["title", "id","lastpost"]}
    }
```

If you want to apply sort on multipule field then you can pass sort param as array as well:

```
body={
        "size": SEARCH_SIZE,
        "sort": [{"lastpost": {"order": "desc"}}],
        "query": script_query,
        "_source": {"includes": ["title", "id","lastpost"]}
    }
```